# VS2022 keys are confused and automatically merged

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If vs2022 is at the end of the line, pressing F5 will delete the carriage return and line feed, causing the content of the next line to be merged into the previous line. Has anyone encountered this problem? The old version of vs does not have this problem.

Is vs doing useless updates?how to solve this

Comment: Are you using version 17.6.5? If not, you should try updating first. If you are using the latest version, you should probably try repairing. Have you searched online to see whether anyone else has mentioned this apparent bug?

Comment: Does this only happen in VS or also in another editor like notepad etc? Does this only happen at the end of the line? What happens if some text is selected and you press F5? Is the selected text being removed?

Comment: Maybe just broken keybindings or changed keybindings by an Extension that "grabbed" F5 for its usage. Maybe start with reseting the keybindings in the options and see if that helps. F5 should be bound to the "Debug.Start" command there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do the following to fix the error:

Tools=>Environmrnt=>Keyboard

Select the corresponding programming language in "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme" (for example, if I use C#, choose Visual C# 2005), and then click Reset.

[image]